# how to save 50 images in a list

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have 50 images on a list. I want to loop through all images and save them with different names how can I do it using `matplotlib`

```
for i in image:
  plt.imsave('image.png', i, cmap='gray')
```

using the above code only one image is getting saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With every iteration, the image name is same. So the existing image is replaced with new one. What you can do is add numbers to it.

For that, use `enumerate`

```
for j,i in enumerate(image):
    plt.imsave(f'image_{j}.png', i, cmap='gray')
```